# Is "to stare at something hypnotically" a correct construction?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> She stared at the washing machine **hypnotically**.

A native English speaker told me that hypnotically was being used incorrectly. He said, "[...] hypnotically isn't used correctly here. What you mean is that the washing machine was hypnotic not that she was trying to hypnotize the washing machine."

Is hypnotically being used correctly here? If not, that's the correct alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hypnotically* actually refers to something that *causes* hypnosis, not someone affected by hypnosis.  Instead you want to say:

> She stared at the washing machine **as if hypnotized**

A more accurate use of "hypnotically"

> The pendulum of the old grandfather clock in the hallway swung **hypnotically** back and forth, and Fred found himself growing sleepy as he waited for Mary to come down.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So the native English speaker was right.

Comment: In this case, yes.  We aren't always right  :)